# CRM form edit using Java Script

Tags: javascript, crm

I am trying to modify a CRM form for an entity called "property".

I want to basically write an IF ELSE statement to do enable/disable a field on the form when the "new property" tab is clicked by the end user on the CRM interface.

I already have written the javascript code but I am not sure of the syntax to create a new property (a new record within the entity)?

I also tried to ID a new property record by the fact the a new property record will have the name field blank.

Please see a sample of the code below:

```
    if(crmForm.all.new_name == null)
    {
    //Enable field
    crmForm.all.new_interestrate.Disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
    //Enable field
    crmForm.all.new_interestrate.Disabled = true;
    }
```

I have set this script on the OnLoad section of the form but it is not running. I postulated that this might be because I am clicking create a new property rather than loading an already existing property?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this, I solved my issue, the flaw was that the field wasn't actually null. I basically rectified this problem using the initial statement

```
    var value = crmForm.all.new_name.datavalue
    if (value < 1)
    {"do something";}
```

This worked for my case as no name value was less than 1.

Comment: Good that you were able to fix that issue. It would be better to check against empty string rather than an integer as i assume new_name is a text field. Forgive me if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Hi Renjith, and thanks for the reply. In my specific case (or my companys case) new name is basically an account number (normally a 10/11 digit number greater than 1). Hence this solution worked for me. Like I said, it was a specific case but I am sure there is a cleaner way to solve the problem.